# Getting rid of white space in a html video after blur effects

Tags: html, css

I am trying to make a full page video. (Something like [this](http://1.bp.blogspot.com/-DaEs003JRW4/UXWgadSSlwI/AAAAAAAAAXM/-xDseadWE1k/s1600/Screenshot_2.png), but a video instead) I have this right now, but as you can [see](http://imgur.com/TJar2ez), there is a lot of white space that is still there. This is the HTML file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Test</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/css/all.min.css">
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="header">
      <video autoplay="" loop="" muted="" class="overlay">
        <source src="/typing.webm">
        <source src="/typing.mp4">WebM Not supported on your browser
      </video>
      <div class="jumbotron">
        <h1>Test</h1>
      </div>
    </div>
    <script src="/js/all.min.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

And here is the CSS:

```
body{
  margin: 0;
  background-color: #000;
}
.overlay {
  margin: 0;
  -webkit-filter: blur(10px);
  -moz-filter: blur(10px);
  -o-filter: blur(10px);
  -ms-filter: blur(10px);
  filter: blur(10px);
  opacity: 1;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
  margin-top: -8vh;
}

.overlay video {
  min-width: 100%;
  min-height: 100%;
}

.header {
  margin: 0;
  height: 100vh;
}
```

Also, I'd like to know how to get the 'jumbotron' on top of the video at some point, but right now, getting the video to play is more important.